# Which browsers don't support location.href and how to process this?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where a PC user's browser (I don't know which browser is it) doesn't have support for `location.href`, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp.

**JavaScript is on. Cause fancyBox shows up login popup, which result is - location.href change to ./admin.php?act=loggedok (as example)**

Can anybody tell me how to detect this and how to process this issue?

Is this possible to lock out this JS code?

`location.href = "http://google.com/";`

Comment: It doesn't sound like you know what the root cause is. I doubt it's `location.href`.

Comment: Yes, corporative clients - are great :( No information, - just "not works" :(

Comment: Dear Stefan. it sounds like i find an answer ... i was amazed, when understood this. Hmm, really sometimes it not work. In IE9 as ex.

Answer (score 3):

the location object of the navigator is supported everywhere.. what you can do is to make a simple check if location is arround and then react to it as you need..

```
if ( window.location){ //or if (location in window) for modern browsers..
    window.location.href="www.google.com";
}
else{
    alert("please enter www.google.com into your address bar"); // :P
}
```

Btw; in a noscript tag, you cant do any javascript, so you cant "react to the user having javascript off". But you can display additional html in such a way, that shows the user he still lives in the 90's and should update his IE3 and enable javascript ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that Javascript support in user's browser is turned on.
As you can see on w3schools web site it is supported by all main browsers.

This link can help: [Mozilla: location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/location)

Comment: is not a question about JS. It is enabled. Function not redirects.

Answer (score 0):

As Andron said all major browsers should support it unless they specifically have javascript disabled. You can tell the user about this using the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: Was not question about JS enabled or not.

Comment: That was just an FYI. As I mentioned first all major browsers support location.href

Comment: My bad, I meant tell the the user. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use

```
document.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
```

instead?

It works on all browsers unless they have javascript disabled

Comment: document.location===window.location evaluate true... they are exactly the same... when you give down votes please try and give a full explanation

Comment: in list of supported browser i dont se konquerror. Maybe this is problem of other browser like NN. PS. Will use also this ... tnx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either that javascript is not supported, turned off, or the browser does not support the location object which is basically shorthand for window.location. thus use:

```
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: Am not taking about JS down. Just - about DOWN this function. Cause redirection is called from fancy-box, which shows normally (i dont have access to PC with this, and can't speak with this person).